# Is the Chern connection of the trivial line bundle the trivial connection?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $M$ be an complex manifold, $L=M\times \mathbb{C}$ the complex linear trivial bundle over $M$ and $h$ an Hermitian metric over $L$. Is the Chern connection of $(L,h)$ the trivial connection? If no, can we give some other assumptions in order to make it true?

Comment: It doesn't have to be; consider the Poincaré metric on the complex disc. You need the curvature to be flat for this to be true.

Comment: The answer is no. Denote by $s_0$ the tautological section $s_0(x)=1$, $\forall x\in M$ and  set $u(x)= h(s_0(x), s_0(x))$. If  $u$ is not constant,  then the trivial connection is not compatible with the metric $h$ and hence it cannot be the Chern connection  defined to be the unique connection compatble with both the holomorphic structure and the  Hermitian metric.